# SELINUX disturb PHP7 to work fine

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, centos7, magento, php7

I am using a Server with Centos 7 and nginx, PHP5.4. I host Magento and everthing works well. And now I just remove the PHP5.4 which is installed and I install PHP7 and I also change everything what is needed

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx 
listen.group = nginx
user = nginx 
group = nginx
```

I also set the SELINUX with setenforce 0 to permissive. I have to note that when I install the PHP5.4 I have to follow that Tutorial https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/troubleshooting-php-7-tcp-sockets-with-selinux-on-centos-7-rhelfedora/ to get php-fpm work otherwise I got a forbidden error.

Now after installing PHP7 and change everything what is needed I get an error if I run

sudo  cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2016/08/10 13:15:54 [alert] 2118#2118: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 100000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
```

on Frontend is a 502 Bad Gateway.
So I thought that it could be the same problem like PHP5.4 so I do that Tutorial again. and nothing still the same problem.

#### Note

I don't changed any folder or file permissions. So where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: setenforce only sets the SELinux policy for the current runtime. After reboot, the default SELinux policy is active again. Did you change the SELinux policy in /etc/sysconfig/selinux?

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek I know but I do not reboot the server so it should work I also tried it out with editing the conf file and reboot to get active

Comment: did you check with getenforce which SELinux policy is active? If the permissive policy is active, your problem is likely not related to SELinux.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek do you have any idea what it could be? I ask because everthing is the same I only remove the PHP5.4 and install PHP7 nothing more

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but if that's the one major configuration change, I'd start investigating there. See if PHP works at all, see if a simple app works, go on from there.

Comment: Exactly how did you install PHP 7?

Answer (score -1):

SELinux sucks hugely.

But unless you know exactly what you are doing I would not recommend disabling it / running as non-enforcing for any length of time.

> where is the problem?

While you could take a few months out to learn how SELinux and the Redhat type enforcement policy is supposed to work (we'll skip over the fact it doesn't always work that way) I expect you're looking for a quicker solution.

Instead:

- offer up a small blood sacrifice to the NSA and Redhat's SELinux maintainers
- relabel everything (`touch /.autorelabel ; reboot`)
- Set it to non-enforcing via the command line (setenforcing 0)
- try to regression test all the functionality of your system
- create a policy for the exceptions with audit2allow
- enable the policy
- sent enforcing on again
- repeat steps above at regular intervals

Or reformat your server, install OpenSuse or Ubuntu and use Apparmor instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your roadmap :) but I do not understand why everthing  works perfekt if I use php5.4 an if I install php7 nothing works ? Now I thought to downgrad to check if something on the system is crazy and.. no after downgrading everthing is fine

Comment: So you mean that there is not similar problem with  ubuntu or opensuse

Comment: As long as you don't install SELinux on them :) In theory you can un-install SELinux from Centos and install Apparmor there - but it'd be almost as much of a pain as trying to fix SELinux

Comment: Trying to understand Linux is like trying to shift the moon's orbit. Technically possible, but life's too short.

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

## cat /etc/security/limits.d/nofile.conf

- soft nofile 10000
- hard nofile 1000000